# Confusion on dup2

Tags: c, file, dup2

What happens if I have two file descriptors, `f1` and `f2`, and I open them to the same file: `file.txt`. From my understanding they will be pointing to different file offsets (unless I call `dup2`). What would happen if there was something different in each file descriptor and I called `dup2`?

Example, If I were to do something like this: both `f1` and `f2` are file descriptors to `file.txt`.  Both file descriptors are opened with flags `O_WRONLY|O_CREAT`, with `f1` being opened before `f2` (in case that matters).

1. write 12345 to `f1`
2. write 678 to `f2`
3. call `dup2(f1, f2)`
4. write 9 to `f2`

What would the `file.txt` have now? My guess is just a file with 123459 in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to understand the question I have tried this snippet:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(){
  int f1 = open ("test1.txt", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT, 0644);
  int f2 = open ("test1.txt", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT, 0644);
  write (f1, "12345", 5);
  write (f2, "678", 3);
  dup2 (f1, f2);  // this closes f2
  write (f2, "9", 1);
  close (f1);
  close (f2);
}
```

The snippet gives this result:

```
$ gcc -Wall -std=c99 test1.c -o test1
$ ./test1
$ cat test1.txt
678459
```

It seems that the file contains first "12345", then it is overwritten and contains "67845", and finally, "9" is appended.

Comment: Thank you! This helps a lot

Answer (score -1):

/*dup2() makes "the new file descriptor" be the copy of "old file descriptor"*/
[you can check the entire file descriptor here](http://linux.die.net/man/2/dup2)

here is a little program...as you said both the file handle point in the same location...and i would open the file in "append" mode.

```
    #include"stdio.h"
    #include"unistd.h"
    #include"fcntl.h"
    main()
    {
    FILE *f1,*f2;
    f1 = fopen("file.txt","a");     //file opened in append So the file pointer would always point in the last location
    f2 = fopen("file.txt","a");
    fprintf(f1,"12345\n");
    fprintf(f2,"678\n");
    dup2(f1,1);                 //this is a function call REMEMBER THAT
    fprintf(f2,"9\n");
    fclose(f1);
    fclose(f2);
    }
```

the output is 
123456789

Comment: This code is mixing file streams and file descriptors and doesn't use `fileno` at all.  It is simply wrong to try that.  The call to `dup2()` should be generating compiler warnings.  Additionally, using file streams introduces a layer of buffering between the printing operations that is not present in the code in the question which is writing direct to file descriptors.  That complicates and alters the answer.  Also, the code uses `"a"` (append) mode; that means all writes occur at the end of the file.  The question as amended by comments does not use append mode.

Comment: The comments were added more than 5 minutes before this answer was submitted.